# IIS 7 Url Rewrite rule doesn't work?

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, url-rewriting

So i have a folder under the Default Web Site , and i wanted users to be redirected to 
ftp.mydomain.com/myfolder/index.asp when user types ftp.mydomain.com (root page). So i added a URL Rewrite rule something like this.

```
<rule name="Root redirect" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
  <action type="Rewrite" url="ftp.mydomain/myfolder/index.asp" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

It doesn't work anyhow, when i put in the link it just shows the default IIS page. I can however navigate to the index.asp page if i put in the link manually.

I'm new to using IIS with URL rewrite, appreciate if anyone could point out what i'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding that match element

```
<rule name="Root redirect" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
    <match url="^$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="ftp.mydomain/myfolder/index.asp" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Hi Jeow Li, thanks for the formatting and your reply. I tried using ^$ but it doesn't work. Still shows the default IIS page. I did a test pattern from IIS but doesn't matter whatever url i put it doesn't match the pattern "^$" . Syntactically error maybe?